# Is there a way to compute an asymptotic formula of $\sum_{n\leq x}\lceil 2\sqrt{n} \rceil$?

Tags: number-theory, radicals, ceiling-and-floor-functions, euler-maclaurin

I was trying to find an asymptotic formula for the sum
$$ \sum_{n\leq x}\lceil 2\sqrt{n} \rceil$$
using Euler–Maclaurin summation formula.. but I really don't know how to proceed in this case, mainly because of the ceil function ($\lceil x \rceil$ is the smallest integer greater than or equal to x). Thank you in advance, every hint/solution will be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you do it without the ceiling function? Having done that, how do $2 \sqrt{n}$ and $\lceil 2\sqrt{n} \rceil$ compare?

Comment: Well ,$2\sqrt{n} = \lceil 2\sqrt{n} \rceil $if and only if $ n = k^2$ for some integer $k$. In general $\lceil 2\sqrt{n} \rceil \geq 2\sqrt{n}$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yep, but more precisely: how much might $\lceil 2 \sqrt{n} \rceil$ differ from $2 \sqrt{n}$?

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to The Phoenix's excellent comment on exact formulas: using summation by parts (by whatever name), we know that
$$ \sum_{n \leq x} 2 \sqrt{n} = \frac{4}{3} x^{3/2} + O(x^{1/2}). \label{1}\tag{1} $$
(For reference this calculation is in e.g. Theorem 3.2 of Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*.)

This sum cannot differ all that much from the sum
$$ \sum_{n \leq x} \lceil 2 \sqrt{n} \rceil $$
we are interested in, because $0 \leq \lceil t \rceil - t < 1$.
Hence, the worst case scenario for each of the approximately $x$ terms in the sum is that they contribute an error compared to $\eqref{1}$ of size $1$.
Therefore
$$
\sum_{n \leq x} \lceil 2 \sqrt{n} \rceil = \frac{4}{3} x^{3/2} + O(x). 
$$

Comment: @ThePhoenix I think the two complement each other, but you are welcome to disagree. If all one cares about is the leading order, going through the manual labour of the exact formula seems unnecessary to me. I also don't I think the summation by part here is especially difficult.

Comment: I think there's also an argument to be made for this approach given the context of OP specifically attempting to use the Euler–Maclaurin summation formula to approach the problem.